# Video streaming over Bluetooth from RPi3 to android app

Tags: bluetooth, raspicam, streaming-video, android, h264

I'm building a robot that is controlled using a Android app by sending commands over Bluetooth. I would like to also get a video over bluetooth to my android app from RPi3. My question here is, did anyone of you ever got his working before?

Since, from my research I learnt that it is difficult to Stream live video over bluetooth. If some one already achieved this, can you please share your experince about the same. This would be helpful for many newbies like me.

I would be glad if I can get come help or suggestions from this community.

**Note**: Please, don't suggest me to use WIFI since, I did use that already and it is working. I want the same using Bluetooth.

Thanks in advance.